# NEXT JS ver^12 Error: Invalid hook call (useTransition of react-spring)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I use react-spring to create this HOC for animating wrapped components but when running NEXT gives the error:
Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

**/components/Animation/Animation.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useSpring, useTransition, animated } from "react-spring";

export default function Animation() {
  return <div></div>;
}

Animation.Fade = function AnimateFade({ children, style, ...props }) {
  const arrChild = React.Children.toArray(children);
  const transition = useTransition(arrChild, {
    keys: (item) => item.key,
    from: { opacity: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: { duration: 600 },
  });
  return transition(
    (prop, item) =>
      item && (
        <animated.div style={prop} {...props}>
          {item}
        </animated.div>
      )
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you're using `react@18` whilst the current stable version of `react-spring` does not support this. There is a beta currently available which should work. There is also an open issue here that you can track if you want – https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/1870